# Como cambiar el remitente de un correo outlook C# Interop Outlook

Tags: c#, email, consola

tengo este codigo para enviar un correo al ejecutar mi programa pero este al enviarlo lo envia con el correo de la persona que esta ejecutando el programa, y me gustaria poder dejar en especifico solo un remitente es decir un correo del cual se estaran enviando los mails pero no eh encontrado algo que me pueda ayudar a resolver esto, estoy usando interop outlook y este es el codigo que tengo:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
                {
                    string MailText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    try
                    {
                        //Using COM to send email
                        Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
                        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                        //Remplaza el texto por otro que se define manualmente
                        MailText = MailText.Replace("[Fecha]", Convert.ToString(dateTime));
                        MailText = MailText.Replace("[Cantidad]", Convert.ToString(VariablesGlobals.OpMgr)+" de "+Convert.ToString(VariablesGlobals.Dir));
                        //FALTA Agregar los correos correspondientes To & CC
                        mail.To = "correo.preba@mexico.com";

                        mail.Subject = "Actualización Programa [DataInformer] " + mes + ", " + Convert.ToString(dia);
                        mail.HTMLBody = MailText;
                        mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;//Cambiar la importancia a alta                                                                           

                        ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
                        Console.WriteLine("Your message has been successfully sent.", "Message");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Message");
                    }

                }
```

mil gracias por su ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar un correo usando otra cuenta remitente debes especificar una
`account` al objeto `mail` de la siguiente manera:

```
mail.SendUsingAccount = account;
```

Para obtener la `account` deberias tener la cuenta añadida a tu sesión actual de Outlook, y entonces ejecutar este código para obtenerla:

```
public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress)
{
    // Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session.
    Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
    foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
    {
        // When the email address matches, return the account.
        if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress)
        {
            return account;
        }
    }
    throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress));
}
```

El parámetro `smtpAdress` es la dirección de correo con la que quieres enviarlo.

[Enlace a la web de Microsoft donde explica esto.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-send-an-e-mail-given-the-smtp-address-of-an-account)

Comment: Solo tengo una pregunta, implemente algo parecido solo que no uso smtp sino que uso el COM de outlook y me funciono algo bien ya que si no encuentra el remitente en la sesion del usuario me marca que no existe y no envia el correo, pero cuando si existe y lo envia el remitente aun lo envia con la cuenta predeterminada y no con la que indico, Sabes alguna solucion ?